# Умный 301 редирект .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте.
Прошу помощи, так как с .htaccess не силен, умею делать элементарные задачи не больше, поэтому заранее предупрежу, что ищу готовое решение ну или умную статью на решение моей задачи.

И так, суть заключается в том, что есть каталог товаров на сайте:

**URN**

`/catalog/phone-new
 /catalog/pc-new
 /catalog/mouse-new
 /ctalog/keyboard-new`

и так далее, их очень много, все они перехали на новый адрес:

`/catalog/phone
 /catalog/pc
 /catalog/mouse
 /ctalog/keyboard`

 И нужно написать 301 редирект, такая же ситуация с товарами:

`/catalog/phone/iphone
/catalog/phone/blackberry
/catalog/pc/macbook
/catalog/pc/hp
/catalog/mouse/razer
/catalog/mouse/logitech`

нужно:

`/catalog/iphone
/catalog/blackberry
/catalog/macbook
/catalog/hp
/catalog/razer
/catalog/logitech`

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а система какая-то существует? например во втором случает выглядит так, что надо просто убрать второй уровень после /catalog/

Comment: @splash58 все верно, нужно просто убрать catalog

Comment: `RewriteRule ^catalog/.+/(.+)$ /catalog/$1  [R=301]`

Comment: @splash58 напишите ответом, я вам плюсик тыкну и приму ответ, спасибо :)

Comment: написал. рад, что помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы во втором случае убрать второй уровень достаточно такого правила

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/.+/(.+)$ /catalog/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Спасибо, пулемет, работает :)